# Use IF statement to search json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I need to search this json file and print only the peole with a Y status:

```
[[{"Name": "person1", "Status": "Y"}], [{"Name": "person2", "Status": "N"}], [{"Name": "person3", "Status": "Y"}]]
```

I can open the file and display the data ok, but need to search within it.
Could someone help complete this if statement for me?
It needs to look at the keyvalue? Status and print only the two people with Y

```
for name in OpenFile:
                    **# if Status == Y  what do I do here? :**
                        print ("Name : " +name[i]['Name'])
                        print ("Status : " +name[i]['Status'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the lists, extract the dict from it and check the key 'Status':

```
for element in OpenFile:
    ele = element[0]  # grab the dict
    if ele.get('Status') == 'Y':
        print 'Name: {}'.format(ele.get('Name')
        print 'Status: {}'.format(ele.get('Status')
```

Your `OpenFile` object is a list of lists, which inside it's dict structure.
So, you want to address the first object in your list (that's the dict) and then perform your check. You do that with `ele.get()`

Comment: A slight variation on this worked. Thanks very much.

Comment: @JohnCollins you welcome, if you found my answer helpful please consider upvoting it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are referencing [i], while `name` is your iterator. Change it to something like this:

```
for name in OpenFile:
                    **# if Status == Y  what do I do here? :**
                        print ("Name : " +name['Name'])
                        print ("Status : " +name['Status'])
```

at the same time, your json formatted data looks like it's formatted like this:
`List[list[dict],list[dict],list[dict],]` so it'd only make sense to navigate to the `Name` value like this:

```
print(OpenFile[0][0]['Name'])
```

Try if this returns person1 and then base your next if-statement on this.

**Additional debugging tool:**
use type() to identify how your json is formatted:

```
type(OpenFile)
type(OpenFile[0])
type(OpenFile[0][0])
```

etc., use the error to figure out how your json is formatted